# What code do I need to make the front-face class show up when I toggle classes?

Tags: css

When I toggle, the backface class goes hidden and the css class changes, but the frontface images don't show up.  I am open to very basic, elementary explanations of this -- there are many variables I don't understand.

I've looked up the rotateY transform and the transform-style: preserve-3d. Those dont' work.  I don't know if it has to do with the specificity.

```js
const cards = document.querySelectorAll(".memory-card");

function flipCard() {
  console.log("I was clicked!");
  console.log(this);
  this.classList.toggle("flip");
}

cards.forEach(card => card.addEventListener("click", flipCard));
```

```css
.memory-game {
  width: 640px;
  height: 640px;
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  perspective: 1000px;
}
.memory-card {
  width: calc(25% - 10px);
  height: calc(33.333% - 10px);
  position: relative;
  margin: 5px;
  transform: scale(1);
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: tranform 0.5s;
}
.memory-card:active {
  transform: scale(0.97);
  transition: transform 0.2s;
}
.memory-card.flip {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
.front-face,
.back-face {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #1c7ccc;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

front-face {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

```html
<section class="memory-game">
  <div class="memory-card">
    <img class="front-face" src="img/ZihauZhu.png" alt="Zihau" />
    <img class="back-face" src="img/back-face.png" alt="memory card" />
  </div>
  <div class="memory-card">
    <img class="front-face" src="img/ZihauZhu.png" alt="Zihau" />
    <img class="back-face" src="img/back-face.png" alt="memory card" />
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to rotate `.front-face` 180 degree so it was invisible because of the `backface-visibility: none`. I changed `.memory-card.flip` to `.memory-card:active` to showcase the solution. Click on the card to see the end result.

```css
.memory-game{
  width: 640px;
  height: 640px;
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  perspective: 1000px;
}
.memory-card {
  width: calc(25% - 10px);
  height: calc(33.333% - 10px);
  position: relative;
  margin: 5px;
  transform: scale(1);
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: tranform .5s;
}
.memory-card:active{
  transform: scale(.97);
  transition: transform .2s;
}
.memory-card:active {
  transform:rotateY(180deg);
}
.front-face,
.back-face {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #1c7ccc;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.front-face {
  transform:rotateY(180deg);
}
```

```html
<body>
<section class= "memory-game">
  <div class="memory-card">
    <img class="front-face" src="https://picsum.photos/200/201"
    alt="Zihau"/>
    <img class="back-face" src="https://picsum.photos/200/300"
    alt="memory card"/>
  </div>
  <div class="memory-card">
    <img class="front-face" src="https://picsum.photos/200/200"
    alt="Zihau"/>
    <img class="back-face" src="https://picsum.photos/200/300"
    alt="memory card"/>
  </div>
  </section>
</body>
```